# How to compile a Delphi projectgroup using MSBuild called from an Embarcadero Makefile

Tags: delphi, msbuild, makefile

I am trying to compile the two components from Virtual Treeview (VirtualTreesR.bpl and VirtualTreesD.bpl) which I combined in a Delphi project group called VirtualTrees.groupproj. They should be compiled using MSBuild, but this call is done from a (Embarcadero) Makefile. The relevant part in the Makefile looks like:

```
msbuild.exe /nologo /v:m /t:build /p:Config=Release "$(VTVDIR)\Packages\Delphi 2010\VirtualTrees.groupproj"
```

Unfortunately this results in MSB4040, because the environment variable BDS is not set in cmd.exe, but it is in the Makefile. I tried a SET BDS=$(BDS) before the call to msbuild, but to no avail. I also tried to set BDS as property(/p:BDS=($BDS);Config=Release) which caused another error (something liks: Could not find compiler at %BDS%\bin\dcc32.exe).

This call from the Makefile is part of a preparation to build our product on a CI server, and I cannot guarantee that the BDS variable is set there. So how can I provide the BDS variable which I have in the Makefile to msbuild that it accepts it?

Answer (score 9):

In my batch files, I use rsvars.bat:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
MSBuild SomeProject.dproj ...
```

(You'd have to adjust the path obviously.)

Comment: Thank you. My problem is: I have a Makefile, not a batch file. - andy

Comment: Can't you call rsvars.bat before calling make?

Comment: I tried a few things: If I put it in a small batch and call rsvars first and then the Makefile using make. it does not work. If I call rsvars in the Makefile just before I call Msbuild.exe, it doesn't work. If I call rsvars on the command line and after that msbuild on the command line, it works. Long story short: It works manually, but not from the Makefile

Comment: @andy: Does executing a batch file directly calling MSBuild (**not** via make) work? Could you call such a batch file **instead** of make in your build process?

Comment: Yes, that works. I will see if I can use a batch for certain tasks instead of make. Thank you very much!

Comment: Generally Delphi developers have no need for MAKE as MSBuild does everything needed.